# How to consider maven dependency in java program compilation via command line

Tags: java, maven, command-line

I executed my java file like this:

```
javac -cp ".:/root/Desktop/karim/software/UIMA/yagogit/yodaqa/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar" LATByFocus.java
```

which gives error like:

```
LATByFocus.java:5: package org.apache.uima does not exist
import org.apache.uima.UimaContext;
                      ^
LATByFocus.java:6: package org.apache.uima.analysis_engine does not exist
import org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException;
                                      ^
LATByFocus.java:7: package org.apache.uima.fit.component does not exist
import org.apache.uima.fit.component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase;
                                    ^
LATByFocus.java:8: package org.apache.uima.fit.util does not exist
import org.apache.uima.fit.util.JCasUtil;
                               ^
....
LATByFocus.java:36: cannot find symbol
symbol: class JCasAnnotator_ImplBase
public class LATByFocus extends JCasAnnotator_ImplBase {
                                ^
LATByFocus.java:37: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Logger
location: class cz.brmlab.yodaqa.analysis.question.LATByFocus
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LATByFocus.class);
          ^
LATByFocus.java:39: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class UimaContext
location: class cz.brmlab.yodaqa.analysis.question.LATByFocus
    public void initialize(UimaContext aContext) throws ResourceInitializationException {
                           ^
LATByFocus.java:39: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ResourceInitializationException
......
```

So I wanted to try considering `pom.xml` along with jar file in command line - [pom.xml](https://github.com/brmson/yodaqa/blob/master/pom.xml)

Is it possible?

I am trying to execute these files https://github.com/brmson/yodaqa/tree/master/src/main/java/cz/brmlab/yodaqa/analysis/question

in project : [yodaqan](https://github.com/brmson/yodaqa/tree/master/src/main/java/cz/brmlab/yodaqa/analysis/question)

Comment: Why do you want to run from Maven when that project specifically ships with Gradle and has the ability to be run directly from the build script?

Comment: @MrWiggles: I tried it without considering `maven` which does not work.  and gives error as mentioned, that is why I wanted to try with maven

Comment: You said you used "java -cp", did you try ./gradlew run as detailed in the README?

Comment: @MrWiggles: yes, `./gradlew run -q` works fine, but I wanted to run individual piece of program

Comment: Change the gradle build file to use a different mainClass, then you can just use ./gradlew run as normal